# Manually creating and validating a SessionSecurityToken

Tags: c#, asp.net, wif, ws-federation

I have websites running under Microsoft Identity Model federated authentication and recently I've been trying to create an API in one of them and consume it from the other, the basic problem   I have with that is that this Identity doesn't have an impersonate option and thus I can't be sure that the call is secure.

Thus I am currently trying to manually generate and pass a token in the headers, this is what I ended up doing on the client side

```
var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal();
claimsPrincipal.Identities.Add(new ClaimsIdentity());
IClaimsIdentity ci = (claimsPrincipal.Identity as IClaimsIdentity);
ci.Claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, User.Identity.Name));

var token = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.CreateSessionSecurityToken(claimsPrincipal,"Api Test", DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30), true);

using(var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("Authentication-Token",token.Id);
}
```

But I just can't figure out a way to check if the token is legit in the API.

Comment: Is using something like JWT out of the question?

Comment: Not really, I honestly would prefer do it any other way then the one I am trying, but I really want to know if what I am trying to do is even possible, like why is there an option to manually create that token if there is no method to manually validate it.